# Capture complete process structure/stack

Tags: process, ps

There are a lot of java processes running on the server, generally, we capture the PIDs of the java processes using command 'ps -ef | grep java'. In general, the java processes have a lot of jars in their structure like the following

```
java -DCORDYS_INSTALL_DIR=/opt/abcd/clouprod01 \
     -cp "/opt/abcd/clouprod01/scp.jar:/opt/abcd/clouprod01/scp.jar:/usr/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar::/usr/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar: com.eibus.tools.admin.cmc" \
     -DProcessName=ABCD
```

In the above java process, there are a few parameters which are passed as arguments to the java process like "-DProcessName=ABCD".

In my case, for a few java processes, there are almost 50 jar files which get loaded when the java process starts. As a result of that, the result of the ps command is not showing the full structure/stack of the java process. The results are coming like

```
java -DCORDYS_INSTALL_DIR=/opt/abcd/clouprod01 -cp "/opt/abcd/clouprod01/scp.jar:/opt/abcd/clouprod01/scp.jar:
```

Can anyone help us in tracing the full structure/stack of the java process using either the `ps` command or any other command?

Answer (score 2):

On RHEL/CentOS in the bash shell, this is usually the result of ps truncating output. In this case, you can add two 'w's to the ps options to get the full command line:

`ps -efww | grep java`

There are more than likely similar options available for your ps binary, if the 'w' option doesn't accomplish it or isn't available.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want the full command line of the process.

Under Linux or *BSD, pass `ww` to the `ps` command to tell it not to truncate command lines.

```
ps -A ww
```

You can extract just the arguments (including the command name) by passing `-o args` to `ps`.

```
ps -o args -A ww
```

Under Linux, you can pass `-C java` to list only processes running a command called `java`.

```
ps -o args -C java ww
```

Another way to get unlimited width instead of the terminal width is to pipe through another program.

```
ps -o args -C java | cat
```

Under Linux, you can retrieve the whole process command line from `/proc/$pid/cmdline` where `$pid` is the process ID. The command line is stored unambiguously, with null bytes to separate arguments, so this is good even if the arguments contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `/proc` filesystem for this sort of thing.  In particular, I think you'll want to look at `/proc/$PID/maps`.  "$PID" is the process ID in question.  You can use something like `cat /proc/$PID/maps` to get a text version of what's mapped in where for any given PID. `cat /proc/self/maps` for starters: that will show you what a simple C program maps in.

I found a "cat" example program in Java, and did `java cat /proc/self/maps`.  That simple "cat" had a large number of ".so" loadable libraries, but only `rt.jar` mapped in as a .jar file.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to use Solaris, you can get the full argument list with one of:

```
/usr/ucb/ps -alxww
```

or

```
pargs $pid
```

Beware that you'll still get a truncated list for the processes you don't own unless you have extra privileges (typically being root).

Not sure if you really want to get the process stack too but just in case, the command to display it would be (assuming pid is a variable containing the JVM process ID):

```
pstack $pid
```

Comment: hi @jlliagre, i am also using Solaris, but i am not able to get the complete command using Example:

`bash-3.2$ /usr/ucb/ps -alxwww | grep ftf.sh | head -1

 0 39548   737   693  0  23 20 5112 3952 603110c3e70 S ?        248:52 /usr/bin/bash /proj/cmp01/app/ftf/bin/ftf.sh -y -c /proj/cmp01/app/btws/cfg/btw

bash-3.2$ 
` 
Even pargs also not working in my case.

`bash-3.2$ for i in `/usr/ucb/ps -alxww | grep -v "alxww" | grep ftf | grep -v grep| awk '{print $2}'|head -1`; do pargs $i; done
 
pargs: cannot examine 39548: no such process or core file
`